# Convert object to array of type integer and sum the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to convert JavaScript object to array of type integer and add all the values in array and convert back to object.

So far I tried the following:

```
//Convert object to array
var arr = Object.keys(some_object).map(function(k){
    return some_object[k];
})

//Remove null values
var arr_without_null = arr.filter(function(n){
    return n !=  undefined;
})

//Convert array to array of type int
var arrOfNumbers = arr_without_null.map(function(x){
    return parseInt(x);
});

//Add all the values
self.sum = arrOfNumbers.reduce(add, 0);

function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
console.log("sum values: ", sum);
```

But this looks ugly and too many steps to what I want to achieve. Is there any better way to achieve the same?

Note: I don't mind achieving this with jquery but I prefer javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave out the `filter` by treating `null` as `0` (since this is a sum), and that means you can combine the two `map`s. Also note that you don't have to supply the second argument to `reduce` for sums; the first call will just use the first two entries:

```
self.sum =
  Object.keys(self.data.CallsByDisposition)
    .map(function(k) { return parseInt(self.data.CallsByDisposition[k] || "0"); })
    .reduce(function(s, e) { return s + e; });
```

There we're relying on the fact that `null` is *falsy*`and using JavaScript's curiously powerful`||`operator to get`"0"`instead of`null`to pass into`parseInt`. Of course, that will also substitute`"0"`for`""`(and`false`and`NaN`and all the other falsy values), so adjust as necessary (your original code weeded out just`null`and`undefined`but left`false`,`NaN`, and such).

See <sup>1</sup> below for a note on `parseInt` and number conversion in general.

Live example:

```js
var self = {
  data: {
    CallsByDisposition: {
      a: 7,
      b: 30,
      c: null,
      d: 5
    }
  }
};
self.sum =
  Object.keys(self.data.CallsByDisposition)
    .map(function(k) { return parseInt(self.data.CallsByDisposition[k] || "0"); })
    .reduce(function(s, e) { return s + e; });
console.log("sum values: ", self.sum);
```

---

Using ES2015 and above:

```
self.sum =
  Object.keys(self.data.CallsByDisposition)
    .map(k => parseInt(self.data.CallsByDisposition[k] || "0"))
    .reduce((s, e) => s + e);
```

Live example:

```js
let self = {
  data: {
    CallsByDisposition: {
      a: 7,
      b: 30,
      c: null,
      d: 5
    }
  }
};
self.sum =
  Object.keys(self.data.CallsByDisposition)
    .map(k => parseInt(self.data.CallsByDisposition[k] || "0"))
    .reduce((s, e) => s + e);
console.log("sum values: ", self.sum);
```

---

Using `Object.values`, which will be in ES2017 and can be shimmed today:

```
self.sum =
  Object.values(self.data.CallsByDisposition)
    .reduce((s, e) => s + parseInt(e || "0"));
console.log("sum values: ", self.sum);
```

Live example:

```js
// Shim for Object.values
const reduce = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Array.prototype.reduce);
const isEnumerable = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable);
const concat = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Array.prototype.concat);
const keys = Reflect.ownKeys;

if (!Object.values) {
 Object.values = function values(O) {
  return reduce(keys(O), (v, k) => concat(v, typeof k === 'string' && isEnumerable(O, k) ? [O[k]] : []), []);
 };
}

// The actual code
let self = {
  data: {
    CallsByDisposition: {
      a: 7,
      b: 30,
      c: null,
      d: 5
    }
  }
};
self.sum =
  Object.values(self.data.CallsByDisposition)
    .reduce((s, e) => s + parseInt(e || "0"));
console.log("sum values: ", self.sum);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> When using `parseInt`, it's usually best to use a radix (the second argument). It's also important to remember that it will happily ignore trailing invalid characters, e.g. `parseInt("123abc", 10)` is `123`, not `NaN` as you might expect.

An alternative is to use `Number("123")` or `+"123"` (which do the same thing). That has the advantage of not ignoring invalid trailing characters (`Number("123abc")` is `NaN`), but the disadvantage of treating `""` as `0`.

So you pays your money and you takes your choice...

Comment: Ugh, I hate calling `parseInt` on numbers. There be dragons. Well, it's if you get into too high numbers, but still. I'd much rather do `.map(Number).filter(x=>x)` which will only leave valid things to add together.

Comment: @vlaz: Yes, I should add a note about using `parseInt`. But there be dragons in the coerced or `Number` approach as well: `Number("")` is `0`.

Comment: That's true but it doesn't really matter in this case - the `.filter(x=>x)` will remove them along with anything falsey (which would be only `NaN`) and even then they won't affect the sum value.

Comment: @vlaz: The point is that they both have dragons. They just have *different* dragons.

Comment: What dragons? I have no clue what you guys are talking about

Comment: @Satyadev: We're talking about the things I noted in my thing above about number parsing. Also the fact that historically (but not currently), `parseInt` would treat a leading `0` as meaning "the number is in octal." (That's been invalid for seven years, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your solution you could 'merge' a couple of steps

```
//Convert object to array
var arr = Object.keys(self.data.CallsByDisposition).map(function(k){
    return parseInt(self.data.CallsByDisposition[k] || 0)
})

//Add all the values
self.sum = arr.reduce(add, 0);

function add(a,b){
    return a + b;
}
console.log("sum values: ", sum);
```

Comment: Heh, same concept. :-)

Comment: Don't forget the radix...alternatively use `Number(x)|0` or `+x|0` to coerce.